# DIV element cursor behaves inconsistenly

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, dhtmlx

I have a DIV element on a JSP page whose behavior is defined in the following CSS class:

```
.toolbarRight .shortcut {
background-position: left center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:16px;
height:16px;
margin:0 8px 0 0;
display:inline;
cursor:pointer;
position:relative;
top:6px;
float:left;
border:none;
}

span.toolbarRight .export {
background-image: url('/images/excel.gif');
}
```

So basically when you hover over it with the mouse it should change into a pointer. The problem is that it only changes into a pointer over the bottom 1/4 of the element, over the top 3/4 it doesn't. Look at pictures below for illustration of the problem.

Pic 1: mouse cursor is over bottom 1/4 of Excel icon (changes into pointer):

[image]

Pic 2: mouse cursor is over top 3/4 of Excel icon (does not change into pointer):

[image]

Another thing that's strange is that it only happens in my current screen configuration which includes two DHTMLX grids, one in the top half of the screen, the other on the bottom (look at picture below; Excel icon where problem occurs is circled in yellow):

[image]

If I have three grids (two horizontal and one vertical) the problem does not occur:

[image]

Anybody know what the reason for this is?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I have this problem, it's because you have another item's padding overlapping the toolbar (or something else).  Since the bottom 1/4 is visible, then odds are something above it is overlapping below slightly.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what the problem was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers might be right, but you might also have a float issue here.

You can force parent containers to wrap their floated children by applying `overflow: hidden;`. Try that out. If it fails, use a [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Also, I don't know if the width and height of your `.toolbarRight .shortcut` class will stick because you have it set to `display: inline`. Try inline-block or just plain old block when you need to apply width and height to things.

Comment: I tried overflow:hidden and also display:inline-block and display:block. None of those worked though. I am not familiar with clearfix yet. Also, I noticed the images on the left of the one that's causing the problem work fine, even though they use the same CSS class, .toolbarright .shortcut.

Comment: Hmm, in these situations I normally inspect the element in question with Chrome (right click, select Inspect Element) or Firebug. The elements tab lets you hover over items in the markup and shows you an outline of the width and height that each element has behind the scenes. Perhaps something is covering over your divs, like @Joe suggests. Use Chrome Inspector to see if any of the adjacent divs are interfering. Just hover over them in the elements tab and you will see an outline.

Comment: Yep, that's what was happening. Another DIV to the right of it was wider than it looked and it was overlapping with the one in question. I adjusted the width of the other DIV and that fixed the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is your

position:relative;
top:6px;

combo - the element sits 6px lower than where you think. The image may be up higher but the container isn't. Move your pointer to the image, not the container for the image

Comment: if that was true then the mouse cursor would change into pointer if I hover right under the image, but it doesn't.